# Trying to emulate Counter, getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.5

I am looking to get duplicate records on the basis of the multiple keys. I am using Python 2.5 so I can't use `Counter`. I am changing the code to get my desired result but I'm getting `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

```
start ="0,1,2,3"
mylist= [int(x) for x in start.split(',')]
key = itemgetter(*mylist)
file2 = open('temp_src.csv','rb')
f=[]
for row in file2:
   if row(key) not in f: error 
      f.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have swapped `row` and `key`:

```
for row in file2:
    if key(row) not in f:
        f.append(row)
```

Comment: m getting error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: im getting error IndexError: list index out of range for the above code

Comment: So the `row` in your file is not long enough.